# The website with coloring pages does not open. I get an issue (This site can’t be reached) - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting, vps

I have a problem and can't find a solution. I bought a VPS server and gave it the name of my future site with coloring pages, coloringforest.com. It's been a few days now, but https://coloringforest.com/ is down. I contacted the hosting support service, they told me that there were no problems with the server and everything should work. I get the message "This site can't be reached". What should I do? Any recommendation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Had a quick look it seems your getting "DNS_PROBE_STARTED" as well as "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

These are issues in relation to your DNS not your web hosting I would ensure all the DNS records are set up correctly and are all pointing to the correct places. Your domain provider or hosting provider should be able to offer assistance with this if you run into any issues